# .Net CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in Java

Tags: java, .net, parsing, locale

In .Net when handling numbers with unspecified locale I use:

```
return double.Parse(myStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

Whats the equivalent in Java? `java.util.Locale` doesnt seem to include such a thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you can use [NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance()).[parse()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String));

Comment: Doesnt that return an instance of the current *default* locale of the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, obviously, but it is to my mind the closest thing to what you ask, since there is nothing such as InvariantCulture in Java (which I may suspect to have an underlying bias).

Comment: The whole point of explicitly using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is to make your code agnostic of the current culture. The reason there is an invariant culture instead of you just choosing a specific culture is so there is something that everyone can default to for instead of everyone having to choose one.